# How to set the thread stack size from the Android Native application?

Tags: android

On Android, we have C++ native application that creates a new thread using the POSIX pthread library. We are using the `pthread_attr_setstacksize` to set the stack size to 512K (before we create new thread), but stack size always defaults to 1M.
Following is the sample code,

```
     1  #include <iostream>
     2  #include <pthread.h>
     3  #include <sys/time.h>
     4  #include <sys/resource.h>
     5
     6  void* Function(void *ptr)
     7  {
     8      pthread_attr_t attr;
     9      pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    10      size_t get_default_size;
    11      pthread_attr_getstacksize(&attr, &get_default_size);
    12    std::cout<<pthread_self()<<" Stack size = "<<get_default_size<<std::endl;
    13      return NULL;
    14  }
    15
    16  int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
    17  {
    18      pthread_attr_t attr;
    19      pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    20      if ( pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr, 1024 * 512) == 0)
    21          std::cout<<"Setting stack size successful"<<std::endl;
    22
    23      pthread_t thread_id;
    24      /* creating a new thread with thread stack size set */
    25      pthread_create(&thread_id, &attr, &Function, NULL);
    26      pthread_join(thread_id,0);
    27  }
```

So, when i run the above code i always get the following output,

```
CT60-L1-C:/data/data/files $ ulimit -s
8192
CT60-L1-C:/data/data/com.foghorn.edge/files $ ./nativeThread
Setting stack size successful
520515536112 Stack size = 1032192
CT60-L1-C:/data/data/files $
```

Eventhough, the `ulimit -s` stack size is 8192K, and i am explicitly setting the stack size to 512K (line no. 20) in the source code, the output from the `pthread_attr_getstacksize` (line no. 11) from the thread is always 1M.
So I have 2 questions:

1. Is using `pthread_attr_setstacksize` correct way to set the stack size even for Android using the pthread POSIX library ?
2. How can we set the stack size on Android, certainly the `ulimit -s` has no effect on the stack size for the new threads that are created ?

Any help is appreciated

I have tried changing the `ulimit -s` to a different size and still i always get the stack size from thread to be 1M. It feels we cant change the stack size on the Android (like it does in Ubuntu atleast)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to the problem, the `pthread_attr_getstacksize` does not represent the stack size of the current thread.
The way i verified that the `pthread_attr_setstacksize` is working fine by allocating (using alloca) memory on the stack and check if it actually works correctly.

The updated source code is as follows,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

void* Function(void *ptr)
{
    for ( int i = 1,count=1 ;;count++ ) {
        size_t size = i * 1024 * 1024 ;
        char *allocation = (char *)alloca(size);
        allocation[0] = 1;
        std::cout<<count<<std::endl;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    pthread_t thread_id;
    /* creating a new thread with thread stack size set */
    pthread_create(&thread_id, &attr, &Function, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread_id,0);
}
```